# Lost my original avatar

Tags: support, gravatar

My first avatar was created automatically when I registered my email with my account.

Then I changed my avatar to different images, and then I changed my email address.

Now I change my email address to the one used for registration, but I can't  get my first avatar. How can I get back my first avatar?

Comment: Your best bet is the Wayback Machine, grab a screenshot and upload that to imgur.

Comment: I think the avatar was created based on email address only. I would like to know if there is some url where I can type in my email address and reproduce the avatar.

Comment: I'm not sure if Stack Overflow uses the md5 hash as described [here](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/), but if they do, that should work.

Comment: Yes, Gravatar does that but they have been messing around with their generating implementation causing all kind of weird (side-)effects (like having totally different avatars based on the size you requested)

Comment: If you go to "edit profile and settings" and click "change picture" - is the one that shows an identicon (lighter shade of green - slightly different pattern) the one you're after? As far as I can tell - until today that's been your only other image on SO.

Comment: IIRC there was a time where people were complaining about gravatars changing - I think it was because the md5 hash that @Glorfindel mentioned was implemented to help obscure your email address.  But that was 4 or 5 years ago.  Maybe your original one that you remember was pre md5?

Comment: @psubsee2003 yes, my first avatar was much earlier than the hash change.

Comment: @Tim then it is probably lost forever, unless you can find an image of it in the Wayback machine somewhere and save it

Comment: Just for reference: recent mishaps wit gravatar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289854/why-is-se-suddenly-using-identicon-instead-of-gravatar and a dupe with screenshots: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289979

Comment: @rene: thanks. I got it back by the way in your first comment.

Comment: Why do you care too much on profile image?